# websphere commerce - RAD - Data service layer wizard is not working

Tags: rad, websphere-commerce

I am trying to create a new data service layer in RAD. When i select Data service layer in the wizard and on selecting next i get the below exception in the metadata logs

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-07-13 16:38:49.199
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.websphere.command.CommandException
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at         org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.commerce.config.aesmigration.util.WCEncryptionAlgCheckerFactory.parseCommerceProductFile(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.commerce.config.aesmigration.util.WCEncryptionAlgCheckerFactory.getWCEncryptionAlgChecker(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.commerce.util.nc_crypt.decrypt(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.commerce.util.nc_crypt.decrypt(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.commerce.util.nc_crypt.decrypt(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.commerce.toolkit.internal.dataaccess.wizards.SDOGenerationWizard.initDatabaseConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.commerce.toolkit.internal.dataaccess.wizards.SDOGenerationWizard.init(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.command.CommandException
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 74 more
```

The RAD version is 7.5.5.

FEP 7.

We are seeing the same problem across the VMs(VMs are copy pasted in differnt machines). So there should be something corrupted in the source or not properly installed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Even though WebSphere commerce ships RAD, this problem is not RAD related. My advice is that you contact Commerce support.

Answer (score 1):

You might have possibly resolved this issue by now. If not, can you double check, if the JET (Java Emitter Template) package is installed and enabled.

You can verify this using the steps provided in IBM Knowledge Center : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.component-services.doc/tasks/twvjet.htm

Comment: Why should it be enabled via the Java Emitter Template? JET is a plugin outside of the RAD/WCD distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The CommandException/NoClassDefFoundError was a misleading error for me since it covered another error: to discover what caused the problem I found on [Ibm's website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21995421) that I had to add -Xverify:none to my eclipse.ini installation.

Unfortunately a nullpointerexception in one of the Data Service Layer wizard classes surfaced. Investigating I found that for some reason the wc-server.xml was being read but the database password wasn't being either parsed or decrypted correctly. The code launched a nullpointerexception when it tried to populate a Properties with the password. Odd thing: RAD 7 / WCD 7 on Oracle 11 works, RAD 8 / WCD 8 on Oracle 12, on the same machine as RAD 7, does not.

I have devised a workaround, but unfortunately it's not something that I can share.